# Locate link labels and move the labels along with the links

Tags: d3.js, hyperlink, label, nodes, d3-force-directed

I am developing a project on pattern representation through directed graphs. I have reached the point of loading it from a json, placing the node labels, the links between them and that both the links and the node labels move when moving the nodes. However, I am facing difficulties in placing the link labels ("type" in the json) in position (midpoint of the links) and linking to the movement of the links. Any idea of resolution and explanation? Thanks!!!

The actual code can be found at the link (https://jsfiddle.net/obordies25/wmLeganx/2/)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>[AF-PATTERN-EDITOR]</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style  id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
.node {
    fill:#ccc;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
.node-active {
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
link-active {
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-opacity: 5;
}
line {
  stroke: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.overlay {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.link{
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    }
svg {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
}
</style>

  <body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    resolution = 150,
    r = 15;

var graph = {
    "nodes":  [
        {"task": "1", "label": "1", "social": "I", "id": 1, "x": 150, "y": 450},
        {"task": "2", "label": "2", "social": "G", "id": 2, "x": 300, "y": 150},
        {"task": "3", "label": "3", "social": "T", "id": 3, "x": 450, "y": 300}
        ],

    "links": [
        {"source": "1", "target": "2", "type": "N:1"},
        {"source": "2", "target": "3", "type": "1:N"},
        {"source": "1", "target": "3", "type": "1:1"}
        ]
}

/*d3.json("graph.json", function (error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;
    update(graph.links, graph.nodes);
    })*/

var margin = {
    top: -5,
    right: -5,
    bottom: -5,
    left: -5
};

var colors = d3.scale.category20();

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-200)
    .linkDistance(50)
    .size([width + margin.left + margin.right, height + margin.top + margin.bottom])
    //.nodes(graph.nodes);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on('drag', dragged);

svg.selectAll('.vertical')
    .data(d3.range(1, width / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'vertical')
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y2', height);

svg.selectAll('.horizontal')
    .data(d3.range(1, height / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'horizontal')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('x2', width)
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return d * resolution; });

svg.append('defs').append('marker')
    .attr({'id':'arrowhead',
        'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
        'refX':40,
        'refY':0,
        'orient':'auto',
        'markerWidth':5,
        'markerHeight':5,
        'xoverflow':'visible'})
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
    .attr('fill', '#777')
    .style('stroke','none');


var link = svg.selectAll("svg.link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)')

    .attr("data-source", function (d) {
          return d.source;
        })
    .attr("data-target", function (d) {
          return d.target;
        })
    .attr("x1", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.source)
                return node.x;
        }
    })
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.target)
                return node.x;
        }
    })
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.source)
                return node.y;
        }
    })
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.target)
                return node.y;
        }
    })
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
});

var node = svg.selectAll("svg.node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append('g');

node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr('node-id', d => d.social)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('r', r * 2)
    .call(drag);//
    
node.append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr('node-id', d => d.social)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
    .attr('dx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('dy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.social; });

force.on("tick", function () {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

});

function dragged(d) {
  var x = d3.event.x,
      y = d3.event.y,

      gridX = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(width - r, x)), resolution),
      gridY = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(height - r, y)), resolution);

      d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.x = gridX).attr('cy', d.y = gridY);
      d3.select(this).attr('dx', d.x = gridX).attr('dy', d.y = gridY);

      d3.selectAll(`[data-source='${d.task}']`).attr('x1', d.x).attr('y1', d.y);
      d3.selectAll(`[data-target='${d.task}']`).attr('x2', d.x).attr('y2', d.y);
      d3.select(`text[node-id='${d.social}']`).attr('dx', d.x).attr('dy', d.y)
}

function round(p, n) {
  return p % n < n / 2 ? p - (p % n) : p + n - (p % n);
}

</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create link labels as `<g>` elements with a `<circle>` and a `<text>` under each one:

```js
const links = graph.links.map(l => {
  const source = graph.nodes.find(n => n.task === l.source);
  const target = graph.nodes.find(n => n.task === l.target);
  return {...l, source, target};
});
        
const linkLabel = svg.selectAll("g.link-label")
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .classed('link-label', true)
  .attr('transform', d => 
    `translate(${(d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2},${(d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2})`);
    
linkLabel.append('circle')
  .attr('r', 20);
      
linkLabel.append('text')
  .text(d => d.type)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
  .style('stroke', 'none')
  .style('fill', 'black')
```

See it's working in the snippet:

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    resolution = 150,
    r = 15;

var graph = {
    "nodes":  [
        {"task": "1", "label": "1", "social": "I", "id": 1, "x": 150, "y": 450},
        {"task": "2", "label": "2", "social": "G", "id": 2, "x": 300, "y": 150},
        {"task": "3", "label": "3", "social": "T", "id": 3, "x": 450, "y": 300}
        ],

    "links": [
        {"source": "1", "target": "2", "type": "N:1"},
        {"source": "2", "target": "3", "type": "1:N"},
        {"source": "1", "target": "3", "type": "1:1"}
        ]
}

var margin = {
    top: -5,
    right: -5,
    bottom: -5,
    left: -5
};

var colors = d3.scale.category20();

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-200)
    .linkDistance(50)
    .size([width + margin.left + margin.right, height + margin.top + margin.bottom])

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on('drag', dragged);

svg.selectAll('.vertical')
    .data(d3.range(1, width / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'vertical')
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y2', height);

svg.selectAll('.horizontal')
    .data(d3.range(1, height / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'horizontal')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('x2', width)
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return d * resolution; });

svg.append('defs').append('marker')
    .attr({'id':'arrowhead',
        'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
        'refX':40,
        'refY':0,
        'orient':'auto',
        'markerWidth':5,
        'markerHeight':5,
        'xoverflow':'visible'})
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
    .attr('fill', '#777')
    .style('stroke','none');


var link = svg.selectAll("line.link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)')

    .attr("data-source", function (d) {
          return d.source;
        })
    .attr("data-target", function (d) {
          return d.target;
        })
    .attr("x1", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.source)
                return node.x;
        }
    })
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.target)
                return node.x;
        }
    })
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.source)
                return node.y;
        }
    })
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.target)
                return node.y;
        }
    })
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
        });   
    
    const links = graph.links.map(l => {
    const source = graph.nodes.find(n => n.task === l.source);
    const target = graph.nodes.find(n => n.task === l.target);
    return {...l, source, target};
    });
        
    const linkLabel = svg.selectAll("g.link-label")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "link-label")
    .attr('transform', d => `translate(${(d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2},${(d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2})`);
    
    linkLabel.append('circle')
        .attr('r', 20);
      
    linkLabel.append('text')
        .text(d => d.type)
      .classed('label', true)
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
    .style('stroke', 'none')
    .style('fill', 'black')
      
 console.log('L: ', graph.links);   


var node = svg.selectAll("svg.node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append('g');

node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr('node-id', d => d.social)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('r', r * 2)
    .call(drag);//
    
node.append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr('node-id', d => d.social)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
    .attr('dx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('dy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.social; });

force.on("tick", function () {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
        
   linkLabel.attr('transform', d => `translate(${(d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2},${(d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2})`);

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

});

function dragged(d) {
  var x = d3.event.x,
      y = d3.event.y,

      gridX = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(width - r, x)), resolution),
      gridY = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(height - r, y)), resolution);

      d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.x = gridX).attr('cy', d.y = gridY);
      d3.select(this).attr('dx', d.x = gridX).attr('dy', d.y = gridY);

      d3.selectAll(`[data-source='${d.task}']`).attr('x1', d.x).attr('y1', d.y);
      d3.selectAll(`[data-target='${d.task}']`).attr('x2', d.x).attr('y2', d.y);
      d3.select(`text[node-id='${d.social}']`).attr('dx', d.x).attr('dy', d.y)
      
      linkLabel.attr('transform', d => `translate(${(d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2},${(d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2})`);
}

function round(p, n) {
  return p % n < n / 2 ? p - (p % n) : p + n - (p % n);
}
```

```css
.node, .link-label {
    fill:#ccc;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
.node-active {
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
link-active {
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-opacity: 5;
}
line {
  stroke: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.overlay {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.link{
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    }
svg {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, as usual! :-D

Comment: Glad to help, your upvote will be very appreciated

Comment: Thank you. As well I wanted to ask you about what would be the best way to load json data from a .json file. 

Would this code be enough?

d3.json("graph.json", function (error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(graph.nodes);
    console.log(graph.links);
})

Comment: I have added the code and I get error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: graph is not defined" at the line ".data(graph.links)" in your code.

Comment: I think `graph` should be the first argument and `error` is second: `d3.json("graph.json", function (graph, error) { ...`

Comment: Try `fetch` instead of `d3.json` and see if you can load the file. If it's loaded, call `JSON.parse` to verify the file contents is a valid json

Comment: The data is loaded, I manage to print the content of the json file, but then it gives error when referencing it when generating the network elements (nodes, links, labels).

console printout of nodes: Array(3) [ {...}, {...}, {...}, {...} ]

0: Object { task: "1", label: "1", social: "I", ... }

1: Object { task: "2", label: "2", social: "G", ... }

2: Object { task: "3", label: "3", social: "T", ... }

length: 3

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: @OsmelBordiésLópez can you post another question with the problem? I think it need a careful insight.